# What happens to the basic_ostream base when basic_iostream is moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

Just when I thought I understand the multi-pass move construction of iostreams in C++11 (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8156356/273767 for the intro), I ran into this:

**§27.7.2.5.1[iostream.cons]/3**

> `basic_iostream(basic_iostream&& rhs);`
>
> `3` Effects: Move constructs from the rvalue rhs by constructing the `basic_istream` base class with `move(rhs)`.

So what happens to the other base, `basic_ostream`?

I see libc++ gave `std::basic_ostream` a [protected default constructor](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/ostream), which is called here (and also, in contradiction to the letter of §27.7.2.5.1/1, in the normal [constructor of basic_iostream](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/istream)), and does nothing. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you point out, the spec for:

```
explicit basic_iostream(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);
```

initializes both bases.  I've never been ok with that:

http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-closed.html#135

as it causes the **single** `basic_ios::init()` function to be called twice on the same virtual base object.  The committee ruled that this double initialization was harmless.  I disagreed strongly enough that I refused to implement the specification in regards to this detail.  But the spec says to double initialize the virtual base class.

When it came time to specify the `basic_iostream` move constructor, I was in the driver's seat.  And so I specified it how I thought best (to not doubly initialize `basic_ios`).  That decision has yet to be challenged, but probably will be eventually.

Note that in order to avoid the double initialization, the `basic_ostream` default constructor has to be carefully crafted to do absolutely nothing.  And by nothing I really mean nothing.  No zero initialization:

```
protected:
    _LIBCPP_ALWAYS_INLINE
    basic_ostream() {}  // extension, intentially does not initialize
```

Fortunately the base classes of `basic_ostream` are actually specified to do nothing in their default constructors.  So everything just works:  `basic_ostream` default constructs and doesn't touch memory.  Then derived clients call `init(basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>*)` *exactly once* to do the actual construction of `basic_ios`/`ios_base`.

It's a really messy design.  By refusing to double initialize the virtual base, I feel libc++ makes the design a little less messy, and a little more reliable.  This is standard behavior for the move constructor, and not standard behavior for the constructor taking a `streambuf*`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Howard that this is kind of a wart on the standard spec.

In my implementation, I chose to use a more specific call to a constructor extension

```
basic_iostream(basic_iostream&& _Other)
   : std::basic_istream<char_type, traits_type>(std::move(_Other)),
     std::basic_ostream<char_type, traits_type>(basic_ostream::_NoInit)
{ }
```

using a special `protected` constructor in the base class

```
protected:    
    // special interface for basic_iostream

    enum __no_init_t { _NoInit };

    basic_ostream(__no_init_t)
    { }
```

The net effect is the same.